# JS / JQuery Найти индекс массива в объекте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий объект: `subcats = {20: [49, 50, 51], 16: [54, 55]};`

Как можно найти ключ объекта к которому приходится число найденное в его массиве?

Допустим я получил число `50`, значит в `subcats` это значение является дочерним `20`. Тоже самое с `55` или `54` - должны получить `16`.

Пытался методами `find` и `findIndex` но там только простые массивы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить список ключей с помощью [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) и применить `find` или `findIndex` уже к нему:

```js
var subcats = {20: [49, 50, 51], 16: [54, 55]};

console.log(Object.keys(subcats).find(function(key){ return this[key].includes(50);}, subcats));

console.log(Object.keys(subcats).find(function(key){ return this[key].includes(55);}, subcats));
```

Либо пройтись по ключам с помощью [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
var subcats = {
  20: [49, 50, 51],
  16: [54, 55]
};

function findKey(obj, key) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i].includes(key)) return i;
  }
}

console.log(findKey(subcats, 50));
console.log(findKey(subcats, 54));
```